# Cassandra performance issue/understanding

Tags: solr, cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

We have 3 cassandra nodes on which we are facing a problem where our application is working quite slow most of the times. There are many writes that we do per second and that could be one of the reason. Perhaps what we are doing wrong is we are continuously writing on one node (Let's say Node 1) and reading (through SOLR) from the same node (Node 1). So a possible solution that we think of is, to build some logic to change the connection string where we write on all three nodes and read from all three nodes. Will this work or is there a better way?

We have 100GB storage on each of the nodes and there is approximately 10 GB of data on each node. We also saw a case where data on Node 1 where are writing has more data and other 2 nodes has less data. Even this is something we are trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you post your table definition and  query?

Comment: I have 5 keyspaces and about 100 tables in my Cluster, can you please let me know which kind of table's definition you want to have a look at? Also I am doing multiple queries to solr and all are performing slow